Setting change/visual marks with empty inner motion in custom text objects
This has been discussed on Vim’s issue tracker.
By default for the default builtin motions where the 'indside' of a text object is empty - such as double quote (say we have the following text ""), if we perform ci" the cursor will be put between the quotes however, the change marks themselves would actually be reversed, for this very specific edge case, the column value for the start mark [ will be bigger than the column value for the ] mark.
Which some plugins actually use to identify such edge case motions, you might want to put some text in between the quotes, however if the marks' columns had not been reversed you would have no way of knowing you are in the edge case (because for the regular case, where you have text in the quote, e.g "t", the column value would be the one after the quote on the right, in the example with "t" the change text mark's columns would be both the same both pointing at the column position of the letter t).
This is super useful, however I have no idea how to reproduce this with a custom text object and a onoremap.
I have tried manually setting both the < and [ mark pairs, tried reversing them etc., however Vim seems to override those after the onoremap (also  the < and > marks are automatically adjusted, so we can not set the start one to be after the end one) is executed, my use case is the same as the deafult motion
I would like to create a motion for inside % sign for example, that acts like the default ones for quotes, and also handles the special case where there is no-conent in between the pair, so a motion for 'inside' can be correctly computed in that edge case.
Is there any way one could emulate the default behvaviour of the builtins such as single quote, double quote, back tick etc.
Example below has the onoremap commented out, the marks' positions when printed are as expected inversed if we do ci", if we uncomment the onoremap where the marks' pos are manually set, those are not carried out to the opfunc execution, and are useless, seems like Vim is writing them in between the motion and opfunc execution
Here is a test to reproduce: source the vimscript below, and have a buffer with the following line: line of text "", position your cursor at the start of the line and hit gsi" (the custom opfunction will log the change marks [ & ], what i get is [0, 1, 15, 0] for the [ mark, [0, 1, 14, 0] for the ] mark. This only occurs when we are doing an operator + a pair of text object with inside motion where the pair 'inside' has nothing/no content
set nocompatible

"onoremap i" :<c-u>call <SID>TestInsideObject()<CR>
nnoremap gs :<C-U>set opfunc=<SID>TestInsideQuotes<CR>g@

function! s:TestInsideObject()
    let m1 = getpos(".")
    let m2 = getpos(".")

     let m1[1] = 1
     let m2[1] = 1

     let m1[2] = 2
     let m2[2] = 1

     call setpos("'[", m1)
     call setpos("']", m2)
endfunction

function! s:TestInsideQuotes(motion)
     let m1 = getpos("'[")
     let m2 = getpos("']")

     echom m1
     echom m2
endfunction


So... what is your question?

Is there any way one could emulate the default behvaviour for the builtins such as single quote, double quote, back tick etc.

I think you meant "of the builtins". Also, custom operators and custom pseudo-text objects are two different things that can be used together but they don't have to… and it is not exactly clear which one the question is about. You should probably simplify it.

Also, neither the marks '[ and '] nor the marks '< and '> are inverted, here, neither after a classic ci" or after using a custom pseudo-text object. So… not sure what this is about.

In my approach i am trying to create a custom text object, the custom operator is purely for logging purposes. I do not agree that they are NOT inverted, if you test the vimscript above (without/comment out the onoremap) you will see that the custom operator prints the change marks such that the columns of the start change mark [ is bigger than the column of the end mark ] - ONLY when you execute the custom operator on EMPTY quotes.

@romainl  source the script, and then have a buffer with the following line: line of text "", position your cursor at the start of the line and hit gsi" (to log the change marks [ & ], what i get is [0, 1, 15, 0] for the [ mark, [0, 1, 14, 0] for the ] mark. This only occurs when we are doing an operator + a pair of text object with inside motion where the pair 'inside' has nothing/no content (for builtin objects such as quotes in this case single, double and backtick)

Here is a much simpler test:

Start Vim with $ vim --clean.

Insert your sample text and come back to normal mode:
line of text ""


Do ci" on your sample text and leave insert mode right away so that the content of the buffer is not changed.

Check the positions of '[ and '] after ci":
:echo getpos("'[")->string() "/" getpos("']")->string()


You should get the following output:
[0, 1, 15, 0] / [0, 1, 15, 0]

with the two columns being equal because there was no insertion or deletion, so the cursor didn't move.


Now do the same thing, but insert the text foobar. You should get the following output:
[0, 1, 15, 0] / [0, 1, 21, 0]

with the column of '] greater than that that of '[ because adding text moved the cursor forward, after '].
Now do the same thing, but do <C-w><C-w> when in insert mode to get the following content:
line of "

You should get the following output:
[0, 1, 15, 0] / [0, 1, 9, 0]

because deleting some text moved the cursor backward, before '[.
That is the default, sensible, expected behavior of native text objects:

cursor stays put, columns of '[ and '] are equal,
cursor moves after '[, row/column of '] may be greater than row/column of '[,
cursor moves before '[, row/column of '] may be lower than row/column of '[.

and I see no reason to expect anything else.
If you observe a different behavior within your custom operator, then it is either because you introduced it in your code or because the feature is buggy. Either way, expecting that different behavior, and depending on it, doesn't seem like a particularly good idea.

I am not sure i follow, i provided a minimal case in my initial post, which uses vim -u NONE (or in this case a simple script which in no way modifies the default or introduces hidden behaviour). Your example completely ignored the fact that i am using a cusotm operator function and not a built in operator. Which probably makes a difference, i do not know. Yes the example you provided works as you described, however that does not address or invalidate the inital question that i have, have you not reproduced the same behaviour with a user opfunc ? vim -v 9.1

My point is that you ascribe a specific behavior to built-in text objects that they don't and can't have, which is a typical category error. Based on that false assumption, you go on and ask how you can replicate that non-existing behavior in your own custom pseudo-text objects, which is pointless: it doesn't exist, therefore you can't replicate it. As I mention in the last paragraph, the behavior you describe is introduced at the custom operator level, which should be the sole subject of your question. All the text object stuff is just noisy indirection for us and more importantly for you.

I have no idea how you can argue against this, since i have provided a case which reproduces this behaviour, I have seen plugins implementations checking against this column variance to handle such edge cases. Is that expected or a bug i do not know, what i do know is that that is what gets reported with the custom operator.

What I am trying to say is that your whole chain of thought is predicated on the assumption that the described behavior is a custom text object thing demonstrated by your custom operator while it is in fact a custom operator thing.

No that is false, my assumption is not based on a custom text object, since the custom text object is commented out in the script above, my assumption is based on using on a custom operator, simply to  log the mark positions, which is tested above with a built in text object, in this case quotes. I would still like to know what was your result when you tested locally with just the opfunction just as presented in the script above

Howdy folks: I know this conversation is a bit old now, but consider this a friendly reminder to use [chat] for long-running conversations and to be willing to disengage if the conversation becomes unproductive.
